# I want to pass JSON data to javascript function related to web view. But I am unable to get the response data from the Javascript function

Tags: javascript, ios, json, swift, webview

When printing 'b' value, I am getting empty. Means the data I have sent was wrong.

Am I doing anything wrong?

**Here is my code**:

Swift 4.0

```js
let inputPayload: Dictionary = ["wellname": ["answer": "firstName"]]

if JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(inputPayload) {
  do {
    let rawData =
      try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: inputPayload, options: [])

    let b = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "downloadComplete(\(rawData))") !
      print(b)
  } catch {

  }
}
```

**This is my Javascript function**

```
function downloadComplete(a) {
  return a.wellname.answer
}
```

Comment: Your try is wrong `try {  let rawData =
      JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: inputPayload, options: []);

    let b = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "downloadComplete(\(rawData))") !
      print(b);
  } catch {

  }`

Comment: That didn't work for me.Still no use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Objective-c**

```
- (void)runJavaScriptCallback:(NSString *) jsonString {
    NSString *exec_template = @"downloadComplete(\'%@\');";
    NSString *exec = [NSString stringWithFormat:exec_template, jsonString];

    [webView evaluateJavaScript:exec completionHandler:nil];
}
```

**Swift 4**

```
func runJavaScriptCallback(jsonString: String) {
    webView.evaluateJavaScript("downloadComplete(\(jsonString))") { result, error in
        guard error == nil else {
            print(error)
            return
        }
    }
}
```

**Javascript**

```
var downloadComplete = (bridgeMsg) => {
  // escape newline character from iOS sdp
  bridgeMsg = bridgeMsg.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, '\\r\\n');

  const msg = JSON.parse(bridgeMsg);
  // do whatever you want with the parsed json object
};
```

Comment: You are passing a jsonString . but in the java script function, we are using json Object. Then how it will give us solution.

Comment: You can parse the JSON string easily in the JS land. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, buddy!